# What is the best practice to block focus inside Modal Component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm creating an library of components in Angular 8. Right now, I'm creating a modal component that display a window dialog. I want to block focus outside of modal to user only can focus buttons inside of modal with the Tab button. What is the best practice to do this?

The content of this control could be generic. I mean, the user can set a custom content. So one solution could be set `tabindex = -1` to elements outside modal to block its focus.

Comment: Use the Angular material modal, it takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [angular material CDK](https://material.angular.io/) for this. Specifically [`cdkFocusTrap`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview) which traps focus inside some element.

Example from the docs:

```
<div class="my-inner-dialog-content" cdkTrapFocus>
  <!-- Tab and Shift + Tab will not leave this element. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for